# Basic Android Eclipse Development Errors

Tags: java, android

(Solved) Thanks to NetCat: it was a UI XML problem :)

Today I have started Android development, i'm using a Mac with Eclipse and the Android SDK install and all working (I have successfully managed to get working a few "Hello World" type apps working) and for the Android device i'm using my new HTC Incredible S.

So the code below should work and their are no error is the debugger when I run it on my phone, but each time I do before it even loads, the phone pops up a message saying "The application Count (process com.count) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try agin."

I have re created the project several times with different SDK versions 1.5 and 2.2 but still no luck.

The code is from another tutorial I successfully worked through but i have changed some of the variables to make a slightly different app. Can you tell me what is wrong with the following code:

```
package com.count;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class count extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


//Declare widgets
Button btnSave, btnUp, btnDown;
TextView lblCurrentCount, lblCountCard;

//Declare variables
int intCount=0;
int intCardCount=0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Sets up the link between java and the XML widgets
    btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUp);
    btnDown = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDown);
    lblCurrentCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblCurrentCount);
    lblCountCard = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblCountCard);

    //Initialize widgets
    lblCurrentCount.setText(String.valueOf(intCount));
    lblCountCard.setText("");

    //Define button listeners
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnUp.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDown.setOnClickListener(this);

}

//When any button is clicked
@Override
public void onClick(View src) {

    //Actions when buttons are clicked
    switch(src.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnSave:
        lblCountCard.append("\n#" + intCardCount + " " + intCount);
        intCardCount++;
        intCount=0;
        lblCountCard.setText(String.valueOf(intCount));
        break;
    case R.id.btnUp:
        intCount++;
        lblCountCard.setText(String.valueOf(intCount));
        break;
    case R.id.btnDown:
        intCount--;
        lblCountCard.setText(String.valueOf(intCount));
        break;
    }

}
}
```

Thanks Dave

Comment: Could you give a stack trace please? You can find this in the DDMS tab in eclipse. Click it and go to Logcat, and click the RED e Button and post all of it, this'll help use diagnose your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You must supply a layout_width
>   attribute.

That's probably it.  You've got a layout element without a layout_width (and probably, if you make the same kinds of mistakes I do, a layout_height) attribute.  Find it, add the attributes, and see what comes next.

Comment: this was it, after the first guy mentioned netcat i found it :) did not know about that one!